# Access pull request changes programmatically in Azure DevOps pull request validation pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

for pipelines that are triggered to validate a pull request, is it possible to access the PR information from the pipeline? such as what is changed

I have a large repository of scripts and configs and it doesn't make sense to check all of them if only a few files are touched in a PR

I have looked at this but it doesn't have much information
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/pull-request-status?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 1):

From the pipeline that is configured as the part of the build Policy for your PR, you could use the `$(Build.SourceVersion)` variable and call the [Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/powershell?view=azure-devops#use-the-oauth-token-to-access-the-rest-api) to find out what was [changed in a Commit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get%20changes?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1). Or maybe just do it with a git command `git diff COMMIT`

And from there, based what was changed and what you want to test, set [environment variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-a-multi-job-output-variable), that you then use in [conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to only run certain Stages\Jobs\Steps in your pipeline. Depending on what you need to validate or test...

Another easier route to consider is creating separate validation pipelines for the different parts of the Scripts repository. Then for your Branch Policy that triggers the PR, configure **path filters** for your each of your Build policies, so that a pipeline is only run if a change is made to files in a given path.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

on dev.azure.com portal, if you go to pipelines and last run click on the link, [image: first page] and the highlight here [image: PR link] which will take you to the GitHub with changes in the pull request

Comment: Please see the updated question, I'm looking for a way to access the change programmatically